# Set Permissions on SharePoint Application Pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, user-permissions, applicationpage

I have developed a number of application pages using visual studio 2010 and deployed them on SharePoint 2010.

All the pages have been extended from `LayoutsPageBase`.

Currently all the application pages are accessible by any authenticated users. However I would like to allow certain groups/permission to access these pages and disallow access for other groups/permissions.

My question:

How can I set the permissions for application pages to be accessible only by certain groups on the SharePoint level and on the code level?

Answer (score 10):

Override a combination of these properties from [LayoutsPageBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.aspx):

- [RequireDefaultLayoutsRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.requiredefaultlayoutsrights.aspx)
- [RequireSiteAdministrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.requiresiteadministrator.aspx)
- [RightsRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.rightsrequired.aspx)
- [SupportsReadOnlySite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.supportsreadonlysite.aspx)

These properties are used by the [CheckRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.checkrights.aspx) method to grant or deny access to an application page.

If you need something more specific than these properties offer, set [RightsCheckModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.rightscheckmode.aspx) to None and then write your own code that throws the following exception if the user should not have access:

```
SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied((Exception) new UnauthorizedAccessException());
```

Following the convention of the LayoutsPageBase class, this custom code should be called by your override of either the [OnLoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.onloadcomplete.aspx) or [OnPreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.onpreinit.aspx) events.

Comment: a full example on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: The properties and methods listed cover a number of scenarios. One example would not cover them all. If you are having trouble using these in your situation, I suggest asking a new question.